# VBA for vlookup giving a compile error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vlookup VBA script that when I go to run it, gives me a Compile error: Next without For. I have searched this site and others and found post with similar issues, but can't seem to find a fix for mine.

My main goal here is to VLookup an invoice account in cells T8:T50, and if the Range L8:L50 is blank, to fill in the name of the person responsible for that account.

```
Sub lookup()
Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheet1.Range("L8:L50")

    If r = "" Then
        Range("L8") = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("T8:T50"), Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
    End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `Next r`...

Comment: `Next` only makes sense when you use it with a `For`.

Comment: Next: the inevitable 1004 error when your VLOOKUP fails to evaluate the first argument, which cannot be an array/range.

Comment: I removed `Next r` and now I get a run-time error 13 for `If r = "" then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`For Each` requires `Next` (which in turn can't be used with `For Each` or `For`). You need to initiate a loop over the range of cells in column L. Use `Application.Vlookup` instead because it allows returning an error value without raising it to the procedure, then you can use `IsError` to check for potential errors and just put a placeholder value in worksheet instead.

The Offset function says "Use the value in the cell 8 columns to the right of the current iterator `r`" (which is in column L), so if my math is right, L + 8 = T.

```
Dim val, r As Range
Dim lookupRange as Range, accountRange as Range
Set lookupRange = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A:B")
Set accountRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L8:L50")
For Each r in accountRange.Cells
    If r.Value = "" Then
        val = Application.VLookup(r.Offset(0,8).Value, lookupRange, 2, False)
        If IsError(val) Then
            r.Value = "Error!"
        Else
            r.Value = val
        End If
    End If
Next r
```

Comment: I get a compile error: Variable not defined for `r`

Comment: Did you define your `r` with a `Dim` statement?

Comment: Ahh, I did not. Got it running now. Thank you so much!